# Need Help React Native Image Header Scroll View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to add a Image Header Scroll View for my Project. I used the below code and which gives me the error
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."
I tried everything i could but i didn't find a solution. Also I totally don't understand why this error is popping.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {Header} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import HeaderImageScrollView, {
  TriggeringView,
} from 'react-native-image-header-scroll-view';

const MIN_HEIGHT = Header.HEIGHT;
const MAX_HEIGHT = 250;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },

  section: {
    padding: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },



  titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  navTitleView: {
    height: MIN_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 16,
    opacity: 0,
  },
  navTitle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  sectionLarge: {
    height: 600,
  },
});

class TvShow extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {showNavTitle: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <HeaderImageScrollView
          maxHeight={MAX_HEIGHT}
          minHeight={MIN_HEIGHT}
          maxOverlayOpacity={0.6}
          minOverlayOpacity={0.3}
          fadeOutForeground
          renderHeader={() => (
            <Text>Hiiii</Text>
          )}
          renderFixedForeground={() => (
            <Animatable.View
              style={styles.navTitleView}
              ref={navTitleView => {
                this.navTitleView = navTitleView;
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.navTitle}>
                Hii
              </Text>
            </Animatable.View>
          )}
          renderForeground={() => (
            <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <Text>Hii</Text>
            </View>
          )}>
          <TriggeringView
            style={styles.section}
            onHide={() => this.navTitleView.fadeInUp(200)}
            onDisplay={() => this.navTitleView.fadeOut(100)}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              <Text>Hii</Text>, ( 1998)
            </Text>
          </TriggeringView>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Overview</Text>
            <Text>Hii</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.section, styles.sectionLarge]}>

          </View>
        </HeaderImageScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TvShow;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a library problem, use the version 0.10.3
"react-native-image-header-scroll-view": "0.10.3"

Comment: version 0.10.3 only support react navigation up to version 5. If you are using version 6 or above this library won't work